# Maltego transform with Canari Framework: set relationship

Tags: python, frameworks

I am developing a Maltego transform with Canari Framework. The transform works like a charm. But I have issues to set the correct link relationship.

The [docs](http://canari3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/canari.maltego.message.html) suggest to write a transform like this:

```
def do_transform(self, request, response, config):
    return (response + IPv4Address('74.207.243.85', link_label='This is a link label'))
```

And the result looks like this:

[image: basic transform]

I would like to invert the relationship. The link should actually point from `74.207.243.85` to `alpine.paterva.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you switched around the input entity with what you should be outputting to response. The input entity should be a maltego.IPv4Address type, and you should be adding a maltego.Domain to response.

Overall this transform class should look something along the lines of (assuming you're running the transform on an IPv4Address):

```
class TransformName(Transform):
    input_type = IPv4Address
    def do_transform(self, request, response, config):
        response += Domain(fqdn='alpine.paterva.com')
        return response
```

This will return a directed graph with a link coming from the IPv4Address and pointing to the Domain name.

Take a look at http://www.canariproject.com/en/latest/canari.quickstart.html#working-with-input-entities for more help and examples. It's a great read.